# Save Chrome dev console html changes

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

The Chrome "Inspect element" HTML editor is very easy to use with lots of cool features, I love the collapsible elements, highlighting, and live updates so I can see exactly what's happening. Usually when I'm writing I'll create an empty file and open it in Chrome so I can start there. Unfortunately I have to copy everything to the document whenever I want to save and if I accidentally click on a link I lose everything. Is there an extension or something I can use to save the file (Maybe even to google drive?) I've recently accidentally lost a bunch of work a couple times in a row so I need to change something. I've tried brackets, atom.io, shiftedit, and codepen but none of them have the convenience and features of Chrome's console.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces) feature to work with files from DevTools so changes will persist to your computer automatically. Works with all source file types.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to use this from the documentation. I've added a folder but then there's two different index.html and I'm confused. Would you mind explaining in detail how to set this up?

Comment: Specifically in all the screenshots they're working with an empty source tree but I can't figure out how to open the tools aside from inspecting an existing page.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/?hl=en) in Chrome DevTools. The code snippets are stored in the browser, and you can run them on any page/site. I find them very useful myself.

Answer (score 0):

You see the DOM in the "Elements" panel. The page may have JS that changes the DOM Tree.
So what you see in the Elements panel is not the source HTML. Therefore you can't just change things in the elements panel and save the changes to your HTML file.